# RJ45 jack with 8 and 10 pin difference

Tags: ethernet, rj45

I need to use the next Ethernet interface design which it's got a RJ45 10 pin, the schematic looks like this:

[image]

(The RJ45 datasheet is: https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/7499111446.pdf)
(PHY transceiver:https://www.marvell.com/transceivers/assets/Alaska_88E1512-001_product_brief.pdf)

Being a first prototype, in my design I only need to work with low speed Ethernet interface (10/100) and I´m planing to connect to my PCB this RJ45 breakout board:
[image]

The RJ45 datasheet:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/MagJack.pdf

would it work if I'm connecting the PHY_ signals to the respective pins (p1-p8) of the RJ45 breakout board?

i.e:

PHY_MDI0_P            -->       P1

PHY_MDI0_N            -->       P2

PHY_MDI1_P            -->       P3

PHY_MDI1_N            -->       P4

PHY_MDI2_P            -->       P5

PHY_MDI2_N            -->       P6

PHY_MDI3_P            -->       P7

PHY_MDI3_N            -->       P8

I noticed that the RJ45 with 10p it's got a power lines for the transformers
and the 8p connector don't, what is the difference in terms of functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first integrated mag connector is for a Gigabit Ethernet PHY. You can see that from the fact the mag layout is the same for all pairs. It's unlikely a Gigabit PHY can be configured to work with a Fast Ethernet mag, but without knowing it's type, we can't answer that.

Comment: Thanks Janka for the reply, what you mean with "but without knowing it's type" could you explain more this please?

Comment: I have missed the datasheet of the PHY you had linked. Sorry. Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about the mag which may be used nor how ut has to be connected. This is the relevant datasheet: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiz54jShcbYAhXM_KQKHfGnDRYQFgg1MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marvell.com%2Fdocuments%2FEoXWrBLUVWybgXVagKkF%2F&usg=AOvVaw3GK_4NIMwLYFbnuGEMBdqu

Comment: Try it with P3 and P6 to Vdd, with a 1nF cap to GND as near as possible to the mag, P1 to MDIP[0], P2 to MDIN[0], P7 to MDIP[1], P8 to MDIN[1].

Comment: Thanks Janka, it makes sense. What about P4 and P5? should I connect them to GND?

Comment: From what the Sparkfun datasheet says, they aren't connected to anything inside the mag connector.